# Is SITECORE_API_KEY under XM Cloud App Environment variable is treated as X-API-Token for GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud

Team, on `XM Cloud` i can see the environment variables like below..
Along with `GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT` i am assuming, `SITECORE_API_KEY` is the  key which we can pass with X-API-Token to validate. When i tried, it was not working but if it is meant for something else, i would like to know, where we can use it??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SITECORE_API_KEY` is the token you need to pass in the header of your request to Experience Edge.

The correct format is:

```
{
"X-GQL-Token": "XXX_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE_XXX"
}
```

This is for use only on the Experience Edge delivery end point (https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1)

For your preview end point on your CM instance, (https:///sitecore/api/graph/edge) - you need to use the Guid of the API Key item you have created under the path: `/sitecore/settings/services/api keys`

Comment: I tried this, but it was not working for me. Let me try one more time.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. it worked for me.